# After transferring the domain to another registrar, sub domains stopped working. NS is still same

Tags: domains, domain-registrar

This is kind of a mystery to me.

I have recently transferred a domain name from GoDaddy to NameCheap. The DNS I am using is CloudFlare.

Since the time transfer has completed, I see that while the main domain is working fine, I see that *some* of the subdomains are not working (or timing out).

As I understand there is no *domain propagation* involved in this change since DNS and NS remains exact same across registrars. (Perhaps whatever propagation is needed is done at the root which shouldn't affect the DNS entries )

Can someone please enlighten me what can be the reason of these sub-domains not working?

[Update: As expected, all sub-domains are now working as they should. However, the mystery continues, why did the sub-domains go down for those few hours?]

Comment: "timing out" sounds like a web server is down.   It could be a coincidence that it happened around the same time as your domain transfer, or maybe you had hosting for that domain with GoDaddy.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Well, some of those subdomains were simply CNAME. For example. mail.mydomain.com was a CNAME to *ghs.googlehosted.com* , and there were 10-12 other sub-domains which were CNAME to several other hosts. For sure, Google mail and others won't decide to go down during the time my domain was transferred :) Also, I am not hosting the domain at GoDaddy or NameCheap.

Comment: Have you tested it using a DNS tool?    Is the DNS still working?   I usually use `dig` on the command line for that.

Comment: A transfer between two registrars do not change the nameservers attached to the domain. There may be two related factors though: if you use previous registrar nameserver he may decide (based on your contract with him) to stop resolving your domain on its nameservers as soon as you transfer the domain out of it; and you may instruct your new registrar to change nameservers right after the transfer completion, and if they are not configured correctly then it will appear as if the transfer broke everything, where it is the subsequent nameservers change.

Comment: "Can someone please enlighten me what can be the reason of these sub-domains not working?"  for that one would have needed to know the real name involved, the tests you have made that made you arrive to the conclusion of lost subdomains, and the expected results you wanted. Without all of that everyone is in the blind.